# how can I write @... email pattern , using regix

Tags: regex, email

I want to validate an email field using regex in such a way that my email has to has @moore in it.
like a@moore.af, b@moore.sg, and so on. how can I write its pattern? I am using typescript and angular reactive form.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `([\w-\.]+@moore\.[\w+]{1,5})` to match an email address, as I left a 1-5 characters' space for the domain name.

In JavaScript flavour: `const regex = /([\w-\.]+@moore\.[\w+]{1,5})/gm;` then you can use `regex.test(str)` to validate the email field.

**Edit:**

As @Toto pointed out, This regex matches `.....@moore.++++`. Better regex would be:
`([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+@moore\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.]{1,5})`

to only accept alphabet/number in the domain name.

Comment: This regex matches `.....@moore.++++`, not sure it is a valid email address.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Toto, I updated the answer with a better solution to reflect this.